# How to avoid AttributeError and get an undefined value in Python?

Tags: python, object

I'm somewhat new to Python and I want to create a function that takes a parameter that is an dictionary that contains multiple entries. The function has an object with some given properties (e.g.: color, title, description...). If the dictionary from the paramter contains an entry named 'color' it should give the object's property the value of 'color', otherwise the property 'color' in the object should be undefined/empty. I know that in JavaScript this is simply done as following:

```js
function test(params) {
    obj = { prop_1: params.prop_1, prop_n: params.prop_n }
}
```

However, when I do this in Python and params does not contain 'prop_1' it will return an error and stop. I know I can use 'try:' to solve this:

```
def test(params):
    obj = Object()

    try:
        obj.prop_1 = params.prop_1
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    try:
        obj.prop_n = params.prop_n
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

However I hope there is a simpler/shorter way to do this with over 10 properties in Python, any ideas how?

Comment: What is `params` in the Python code? Is this a dictionary or an object?

Comment: You are mixing two separate data structures here: dictionary and object. First you need to clarify which one you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry if the description of my problem was unclear, still [Tichondroma](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1907906/tichodroma) was able to solve it :)

Comment: The way you use `params` suggests that it's an object (accessing attributes using `.prop_1`). If it was a dictionary, you would access the respective entry using `params[prop_1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `params` is a `dict` type you could use [`dict.get(key [, default])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
>>> params = {"foo": 12}
>>> params.get("bar", None)
None
```

Where `None` is a default value if `bar` key not exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary as `params` and [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
def test(params):
    obj = Object()
    obj.prop_1 = params.get("prop_1", None)
    obj.prop_2 = params.get("prop_2", None)
```

Comment: @ericornelissen You are free to upvote and accept any answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are a separate data type in python. They have an update-method, for example, if you have a default color, and want to update the color if it exists in params:

```
def test(params):
    obj = {'color': 'black'}
    obj.update(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input variable `params` is a dictionary, and you want to update the attributes of an object, you can do it by iterating over the dictionary entries:

```
class SomeClass():
    pass

def test(params):
    obj = SomeClass()

    for key,val in params.iteritems():
        setattr(obj, key, val)
```